# CSS on Hover to affect elements in another container (bootstrap card)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am trying to change the colour of **title** and **text** inside the **card-body class** container when I hover the image...
I have already looked many similar examples for hover affecting other elements that utilizes + or ~ selectors. My main problem is because the elements I want to change are outside the parent container, I can't seem to get it work unless I put them under the same container. I would appreciate for tips on how to achieve this without using JavaScript.

```css
.card-header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  transition:transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.card img:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.card-header img:hover + .card-body h5{
  color:var(--secondary-color);
}

/* I am stuck here */
.card-header img:hover + .card-body h5{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card text-center mb-5 mb-sm-5">
  <div class="card-header">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" >
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Title</h5>
    <p class="lead">Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

- Remove the padding from `card-header` and re-apply it to the `img`. Now if you hover over *any part* of the `card-header`, you are also hovering over the `img`
- Apply adjacent sibling `CSS` from the `card-header`

```css
.card-header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  transition:transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.card img:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.card-header img:hover + .card-body h5{
  color:var(--secondary-color);
}

/* I am stuck here */
.card-header img:hover + .card-body h5{
  color:purple;
}

.card-header {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.card-header img {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
}

.card-header:hover + .card-body .card-title,
.card-header:hover + .card-body .lead {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card text-center mb-5 mb-sm-5">
  <div class="card-header">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" >
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Title</h5>
    <p class="lead">Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for awesome tricks and solution! Are those padding values from bootstrap or did you make them up?

Comment: @YongJunJung These padding numbers came from Bootstrap. I found them by looking at your code example in the browser dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

the `"+"`-selector selects the element after the selected element. Your selector should be to achieve this:

```
.card-header:hover + .card-body h5
```

an selector for hovering on image and change styling of h5 is not possible in pure css.

here is the optimized code:

```css
.card-header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  transition:transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.card img:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.card-header img:hover + .card-body h5{
  color:var(--secondary-color);
}

/* I am stuck here */
.card-header:hover + .card-body h5{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card text-center mb-5 mb-sm-5">
  <div class="card-header">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" >
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Title</h5>
    <p class="lead">Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this changes the text color even when the `img` is not directly hovered (e.g. the edges around the image).

Comment: Thank you for trying! I know have better understanding of "+" selector.